# Intellisense and compiler offer and accept alternative to `func` as `funcA`

Tags: visual-c++

I've recently moved to VS 2015 while I'm still using the vs10 compiler for a project. And yea, I still have not moved this one to unicode So I was typing along, I had just added a member to a class as:

`LPCTSTR GetDateFormat( ) const { return strDateFormat.c_str( ); }`

Then I went to use it and intellisense offered `GetDateFormatA( )`. I said, "What the..?", and took it. I was surprised to find the code compiled fine! I searched even though I knew I had no `GetDateFormatA( )`. I traced in and it took me to my `GetDateFormat( )`.

I'm at a lose as to find out what this is about with google, what would I search on that would be specific enough to get results?

**Update:** After sleeping on it and because of Ken White's comments, it occurred to me that `GetDateFormat( )` was accually in the Windows API, and so it is. When I typed: `pReport->GetDa`, intellisense dug into the global namespace and offered `GetDateFormatA` instead of my member function name. And of course it compiled as the define from `GetDateFormatA` to `GetDateFormat` exists.

I've never recalled seeing it before; It is rare to create a member with a name that Windows uses. Defines trump for intellisense.

Comment: GetDateFormatA is the ANSI version of GetDateFormat. There's also a Unicode (wide char) version called GetDateFormatW. The compiler decides which one to use based on the UNICODE definition at compile time and resolves it to GetDateFormat. Both the ANSI and widechar versions still exist independently, however, and can be called directly if desired from your code.

Comment: Hi @Ken White. Is this a C++ specification or just something that Microsoft does? Also, all the `A` and `W` variants I've seen were handled in headers.

Comment: GetDateFormat, GetDateFormatA and GetDateFormatW are WinAPI functions, so it's clearly what MS does. See windows.h. (when you have a bunch of hours to burn) to see how it's done. :-) The gist is that both the A and W versions exist, and then an alias to one of them is created without the A/W suffix based on whether UNICODE is defined or not at compile time. That way code can work either way (in theory) without changes.

Comment: Hi @Ken White. Yes, I've seen the defines in the headers. I was just surprised to see this happen at the compiler level. Thanks.

Comment: Why? Both GetDateFormatA and GetDateFormatW still exist in the underlying API; the only difference is which one is mapped to GetDateFormat based on the UNICODE #define.

Comment: Is this a bad idea? I mean, if I were to us `GetDateFormatA` and then convert my project to unicode. I would have to go though and change all the `FuncA` to `FuncW`. Where as `Func` would just work. I don't get the thinking here...

Comment: The thinking is that you use only GetDateFormat and don't worry about it, because it is translated to the proper version based on the UNICODE #define. If you specifically use the A or W version, you have to change your code manually when you decide to support Unicode. The thinking is good, but it doesn't magically make the specific versions disappear, because you may have a reason to use the ANSI version specifically even when you're writing a Unicode app (or vice versa).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150892/discussion-between-lakeweb-and-ken-white).

Comment: The logic is (pseudocode-esque):  `func TheFuncA; func TheFuncW; #ifdef UNICODE TheFunc = TheFuncW #else TheFunc = TheFuncA;`, and then your code just uses `TheFunc` and works either way Unicode is defined.